# Best way to integrate "customization" to the front page

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes, blocks

**#First question**

We are making a Drupal 7 theme for one of our customers.
The company wants to be able to edit the frontpage easily, without any coding skills.

Atm we got this:

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

But this is totally not user friendly.
We made a block, and put block content in it, for this one it was just html.
But what we want is more like a wordpress "customizer" or something?

*Maybe this is something that is totally basic in Drupal 7 but we just missed it?*

**#Second Question**

The people (Employes of our client) that will manage the website when launched. Will they have to work in de basic Drupal 7 dashboard, or is there a way to make your own dashboard in the style of your website?

Comment: You are asking two questions, please remove one of them from this question and create a new question with the second one.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! _The best way_ is rather subjective, and we cannot give an answer about that. Actually, it's not much clear what you are asking, since it's not clear what exactly you don't understand in achieving the task you described. Then, @sanzante is right when he says you are asking more questions in a single post. It could be that for you are two related questions, but for as are two independent questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible starting point, you might use the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) modules.

When you define a custom CTools page (using the Page Manager module included with the [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) module), you can define its layout and content.

Concerning your second question, it is also possible to edit the page without moving to the administrative interface, by using the IPE (In Place Editor) provided by Panels.

You should be able to find many tutorials about Panels, in drupal.org too: https://www.drupal.org/node/1857644

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no out of the box solution like you want to have on drupal7.

the question is what they want to customize.

Only the text and Images?
Just Install an Html editor and use Panels.

If you have some fancy Sliders or things like this I would use "paragraphs" but its alot work cause you have to write the templates for every element.

Or you just keep it userunfriendy and hope they pay you for changing the content:)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kerim, it would help to have a scope of what the client needs to be able to customize.

Drupal does offer a lot of themes and modules that have "customizable UIs" built into them, but I personally feel they all still assume a great deal of skill and can put you in a position to offer endless support.

My suggestion is scope out what they want to customize, and build those items into custom content types.  Then just assign the regions to different blocks throughout the page, i.e. "header photos," "sidebar links," "main content" - then they can fill one form, and it will dynamically flesh out the site for them.

I used this approach for a major real estate company to build property templates - they completed one node form, and it snaps everything right into place.  It may not work exactly how you want, but it may set you in the right direction.

Personally I would advise you against exposing blocks to your client directly - they're difficult to parse off with permissions and assume a lot of base knowledge.

---

For your second question, there are plenty of ways to provide multiple themes throughout your site - you can even set your client's UI pages to a custom URL path, and then use something like https://www.drupal.org/project/page_theme to set a theme to only those pages, i.e. site.com/client/front-page, site.com/client/editor, etc

Best of luck!